# Differentiating matrix by a matrix

Tags: calculus, matrices, matrix-calculus

Let $X = \begin{bmatrix}
x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13}  & x_{14} \\ 
x_{21} & x_{22} & x_{23}  & x_{24} 
\end{bmatrix}$

and $Y = \begin{bmatrix}
y_{11} \\ 
y_{21} \\
y_{31} \\
y_{41} 
\end{bmatrix}$

Assume $Z = XY = \begin{bmatrix}
z_{11} \\
z_{21}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
x_{11}y_{11} + x_{12}y_{21} + x_{13}y_{31} + x_{14}y_{41} \\
x_{21}y_{11} + x_{22}y_{21} + x_{23}y_{31} + x_{24}y_{41} 
\end{bmatrix}$

How can we prove that, $\frac{\mathrm{d} Z}{\mathrm{d} X} = Y^T$ ?

I am asking this question to understand the backpropagation while training a neural network.

Comment: You can refer to this wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus. In *Derivatives with matrices* section, it provides details about matrix differentiation.

Comment: I checked but that does not explain how to derivate a matrix/vector w.r.t a matrix

Comment: This document seems helpful https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf

Comment: Differentiating matrix with matrix will be a fourth order tensor. Are you sure you really need that for training DNN?